# Unity3D Interactive Cloth Basketball Net Falling Apart Though Not Tearable

Tags: c#, unity

I have a basketball net mesh attached to an Interactive Cloth with the following attributes:

[image: Component Data on Interactive Cloth]

The mesh is not segmented and is not marked as tearable but as soon as the game starts the net falls apart into individual ropes like so:

First moment:

[image: The first moment]

A moment later:
[image]

I am not great at 3D Modeling and have tried several downloadable nets with similar results. What would you do to keep my net together?

Answer (score 1):

I have made 2 similar basketball games in Unity. What I ended up doing was:

- create a torus in blender with the same number of segments around as your rim and stretch it out into a funnel shape matching the general outside shape of your net.
- create / find an net image that looks like a flattened out net.
- in Unity, import your funnel and use your net image your texture.
- use a shader that supports transparency (like Mobile/Transparent/Vertex Color) and tile the texture so the seems line up both around the net and on both the inside as outside

The resulting mesh should have far fewer polys and look nearly as good but most importantly, the cloth physics work better with it.

Comment: In Unity 5 cloth physics are now limited to only clothing type cloths, any idea how to achieve a similar effect in Unity 5+?

Comment: yes, will let you know how it goes when I upgrade my games to 5.x

Comment: Updated game to Unity 5.  Cloth was very similar. Although the cloth didn't import directly, I was able to use my existing torus as a mesh to my new cloth.  only had to handle select the points as bones in "Edit Constraints" section, and tweak the parameters